# google.script.run independent usage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

Now that the client side of a Google Apps Script is standalone with `HtmlService`, I want the option to develop it independently of the client side (mainly to get the benefits of normal editor, js & css files and not be bothered by sandboxing). This can mean implementing my own doGet/doPost on the server side script, but then I lose the nicety of using `google.script.run` to directly call functions and accept results.

So, is there a way to use `google.script.run` independently?

Comment: Do you mean calling another Apps Script project file from an Apps Script file?  Server to Server?  Do you mean using the `google.script.run` API from a non-Google website?

Comment: the latter (though the former is also interesting)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like call a Google Apps Script Content Service from an AJAX request in a website and get a return value.

[Google Documentation - Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)

That doesn't use the `google.script.run` API, but it's basically the same thing.  If what you want is to run Apps Script server side code without displaying anything to the user, then you can do that with a JavaScript (jQuery, etc) AJAX call to the Apps Script Content Service apps URL.

Suppose you have a JavaScript function named "runAjaxToGetNames".  And it's called with the following line:

```
runAjaxToGetNames("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFyODk/exec");
```

An argument is passed that is the URL of the Apps Script Stand Alone Content Service app.

The AJAX function looks like this:

```
function runAjaxToGetNames(argURL_forAJAX) {

  console.log('runAjaxToGetNames ran: ' + argURL_forAJAX);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    //console.log'xmlhttp.readyState: ' + xmlhttp.readyState);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200) {
      //console.log'xmlhttp.responseText: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);

      glblStoreNames.names = xmlhttp.responseText;
      //console.log'return value into the global object?: ' + glblStoreNames.names);
      //Call a function to populate the store names
      populateStoreNames();

    };
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET",argURL_forAJAX,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```

The Apps Script content service is a file all to itself with only the following code:

```
//This Apps Script is to get a list of all the names out of a Google Doc.
function doGet() {
  var theGogDocReference = DocsList.getFileById('YWY4ZmM5OQ_File_ID_Here');
  var theContent = theGogDocReference.getContentAsString();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(theContent);
};
```

Comment: Note that I specifically said that doGet/doPost is something I wanted to avoid going through